# How to use array in rest API for getting items based on array values

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I have array with id's of list items so I want those items from list using rest.

I found this

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(listTitle)/items?$filter=(ID eq 1) or (ID
 eq 2) or (ID eq 3)
```

So in this I need to use array values instead of hard coded values.

How would I do it if i have an array as `array[j]`

Comment: loop through the array and build your `$filter`. Finally append it in the query

Comment: can u pls help me with the syntax for doing that..

Comment: see my answer @vikash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write some javascript to build your `$filter` and then append it to the query url.

```
function getFilter(ids) {
    var idFilter = "ID eq ";
    var filter = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (i == ids.length - 1) {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i];
        } else {
            filter += idFilter + ids[i] + " or ";
        }
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Now assume that name of id's array is `ids`:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];
```

Now call the above function

```
var filterById = getFilter(ids);
```

**Output:** `"ID eq 1 or ID eq 2 or ID eq 3"`

Now change the query url like

```
"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(listTitle)/items?$filter='"+ filterById +"'";
```

Check [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/naqamaz/edit?js,console,output) how `getFilter()` works.

Comment: Looping arrays is 1980s BASIC style coding; Just use ``'ID eq '+ids.join(' or ID eq ');``

Comment: forgot to think about `join()`. You can add it as answer. I will give +1

Answer (score 1):

Adding this from the comments because I found it very useful and almost missed it:

```
var filterById = 'ID eq ' + ids.join(' or ID eq ');
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(listTitle)/items?$filter='"+ filterById;
```

You can make it even more generic like this:

```
function contains(prop, values) {
    return prop + ' eq ' + values.join(' or ' + prop + ' eq ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the two previous answers, I feel it's a bit easier to read it this way:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];
var filters = ids.map(function(id){
    return 'ID eq ' + id;
}
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(listTitle)/items?$filter=" + filters.join(' or ');
```

or in ES6:

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3];
var filters = ids.map(id => `ID eq ${id}`);
var url = `/_api/web/lists/getByTitle(listTitle)/items?$filter=${filters.join(' or ')}`;
```