# SharePoint REST API Query is Not Valid

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, filter

I am trying to filter a list by multiple different columns, and then when I add the array filter towards the end, it tells me that the query is not valid. I have tried two different methods which are listed in the Verified Answer to the post below:

Reference: [How to use array in rest API for getting items based on array values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162270/how-to-use-array-in-rest-api-for-getting-items-based-on-array-values)

I want to filter the response to only show specific users names.

Here is what I tried:

Method 1:

```
const filterStartDate = new Date('2022-01-01');
const formatFilterStartDate = moment(filterStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const approvalStat = "Approved";
const teamEmps= ["Emp 1", "Emp 2", "Emp 3", "Emp 4"];

var filters = teamEmps.map(function(emp){
    return 'EmployeeName/Title eq ' + emp;
});

/items?$select=EmployeeName,ID,StartDate,EndDate,LeavePurpose,Title,Status&$expand=EmployeeName/Title&$filter=StartDate ge '" + formatFilterStartDate + "'and Status eq 'HR Approved' and '" + filters.join(' or ') + "'"
```

Method 2:

```
const filterStartDate = new Date('2022-01-01');
const formatFilterStartDate = moment(filterStartDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
const approvalStat = "Approved";
const teamEmps= ["Emp 1", "Emp 2", "Emp 3", "Emp 4"];

function getFilter(teamEmps) {
    var nameFilter = "EmployeeName/Title eq ";
    var filter = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < teamEmps.length; i++) {
        if (i == teamEmps.length - 1) {
            filter += nameFilter + teamEmps[i];
        } else {
            filter += nameFilter + teamEmps[i] + " or ";
        }
    }
    return filter;
}

var filterByName = getFilter(teamEmps);

/items?$select=EmployeeName/Title,ID,StartDate,EndDate,LeavePurpose,Title,Status&$expand=EmployeeName&$filter=StartDate ge '" + formatFilterStartDate + "'and Status eq 'HR Approved' and '" + filterByName + "'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it has to do with wrongly placed single quotes.

First, in that first example with the `map()`, after you build the `filters` array, you are going to end up with

```
["EmployeeName/Title eq Emp 1", "EmployeeName/Title eq Emp 2", etc]
```

where you do *not* have single quotes around the values you are checking for.

Then, when you build the full query, you enclose the entire output of the `join()` in single quotes:

```
// you have a single quote after that last "and", and then you use a double quote
// to jump out of the string back into javascript land where you can run the join(),
// then you use a double quote to jump back into the string where you add a final single quote
// and then use a double quote to end the string

theBeginningOfTheQuery + "' and Status eq 'HR Approved' and '" + filters.join(' or ') + "'"

// what that ends up outputtng is single quotes around the entire last section which is no good

theBeginningOfTheQuery + "' and Status eq 'HR Approved' and 'EmployeeName/Title eq Emp 1 or EmployeeName/Title eq Emp 2 or EmployeeName/Title eq Emp 3'"
```

I would change the `map()` to encode the single quotes around the filter values you are checking for like this:

```
var filters = teamEmps.map(function(emp){
    return "EmployeeName/Title eq '" + emp + "'";
});
```

and then change the section where you `join()` to *not* be enclosed in single quotes:

```
theBeginningOfTheQuery + "' and Status eq 'HR Approved' and " + filters.join(' or '); // just end the line here, no need to add any closing double quote
```

Comment: It is always the simple mistakes... Thanks Dylan